# Mysql - Import values into a column from joined tables and two queries

Tags: mysql, join, insert

my task is to have the list of all products with the associated brand.

I have available the following tables:

```
posts    | term_relationships     | term_taxonomy    | terms
---------|------------------------|------------------|---------
ID       | object_id              | term_taxonomy_id | term_id
post_type| term_taxonomy_id       | term_id          | name
brand_id |                        | taxonomies
```

they are related in the following way:

```
posts.ID  ->  term_relationships.object_id
term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id   ->  term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
term_taxonomy.term_id -> terms.term_id
```

the association between the fields is made by a script that assigns IDs as per attached image:

[Query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Up1fc.png)

At this point I have to develop the query for assigning to posts.brand_id the value terms.term_id if the association is in place.

Filtering criteria are:

```
term_taxonomy.taxonomies="product_brand"
posts.post_type= "products"
```

The query logic could be:

```
IF 
    term_taxonomy.taxonomies="product_brand" AND 
    term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id = term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id AND
    term_relationships.object_id = posts.ID
    THEN
    INSERT INTO terms_term_id = brand_id
ELSE
    brands.brand_id IS NULL
```

I tried to translate it into MySQL but unsuccessfully. Do you have suggestion for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a view and and then `SELECT` from that view as you can do with any other table (it is not a table, of course, even when it looks like). It is then a materialized view on your joined tables.

If you want to see what the optimizer does, prepend an `EXPLAIN` in front of it. Then you will see how good it performs. Okay, a bit OT but still generally advisable.

Maybe for that `IF` you need a function? I'm not sure about it. Still, I would recommend views over complex queries as they "hide" those complex queries behind a much more simple query. You can still do `WHERE` and `ORDER BY` and even `JOIN` again. But look out for performance (when it comes to high-load websites, *every* `JOIN` and missing index hurts).

Okay, OT. Maybe this gives you some hints at least.

Comment: So I am going to try with views. Roland sorry, OT stands for?

Comment: OT=Off-Topic ... In your above query you have 2 columns with same name. you may have to alias at least one of them: `mg_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id AS term_relation_taxonomy_id` or alternatively rename the column, if wanted.

Comment: Yes indeed. I fixed it and it works now. Thank you Roland!

Comment: After I 've  created the VIEW from the query and JOINED the posts table ON posts.ID=terms.terms_id I got my result. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. :-) Does it ultimately resolve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to create the VIEW:

```
create view brand2product as
    select 
        mg_term_relationships.object_id, 
        mg_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id ,  
        mg_term_taxonomy.term_id ,  
        mg_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id , 
        mg_termS.term_id ,  
        mg_terms.name

    from mg_term_relationships

    join mg_term_taxonomy on mg_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id = mg_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id
    join mg_terms on mg_terms.term_id= mg_term_taxonomy.term_id

    where mg_term_taxonomy.taxonomy="product_brand"
```

it reports the following error:

```
#1060 Duplicate column name "term_taxonomy_id"
```

The query itself works fine.